# How do I extract data from JSON with PHP with many combined data?

Tags: php, json

I have this string which contains json and I want to display data in php .
I tried

```
$inf = json_decode($myString, true);
echo $inf-> myInfluencers[0]->entity->id;
```

but not working.

```
{ "myInfluencers":[{"entity":{"id":"123286079528097016","payload":{"kloutId":"123286079528097016",
                                        "nick":"mohammed_mrdi","score":{"score":47.25543551618558,"bucket":"40-49"},"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":-0.2046305761210192,"weekChange":0.3516640938320563,
                                        "monthChange":0.7581201162824698}}}}
                                        ,{"entity":{"id":"75716803548010325","payload":{"kloutId":"75716803548010325","nick":"araakgroup","score":{"score":54.9323603520146,"bucket":"50-59"}
                                        ,"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":-0.009862276843456641,"weekChange":0.14323481098688973,"monthChange":8.744154016599673}}}}
                                        ,{"entity":{"id":"165788789554303093","payload":{"kloutId":"165788789554303093","nick":"KypreeAF","score":{"score":68.53700119560989,"bucket":"60-69"},
                                        "scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":-0.04333376347085505,"weekChange":0.3100661156757667,"monthChange":1.8907382052882298}}}}
                                        ,{"entity":{"id":"168040592724049656","payload":{"kloutId":"168040592724049656","nick":"amribrahim98","score":{"score":47.3655074204191,"bucket":"40-49"}
                                        ,"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":0.007253630369177699,"weekChange":0.361995305845106,"monthChange":-0.12981608352198748}}}}
                                        ,{"entity":{"id":"183521696006191168","payload":{"kloutId":"183521696006191168","nick":"ReemAljeally__","score":{"score":52.861448863866684,"bucket":"50-59"}
                                        ,"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":-0.09571927285505666,"weekChange":-0.12303670830488045,"monthChange":1.7138913867458498}}}}] }.
```

Comment: Aftre using second argument as true, you get array, so do so: `echo $inf['myInfluencers'][0]['entity']['idi];`

Comment: you are converting to array and using it as object. try to use `$inf = json_decode($myString, false);` or simply `$inf = json_decode($myString);`. This will convert your json to object. check the demo [here](https://eval.in/928333)

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode it to an object by setting the 2nd parameter as false.

```
$inf = json_decode($myString, false);
echo $inf->myInfluencers[0]->entity->id;
```

You have decoded it to an array. Then you need to use this:

```
$inf = json_decode($myString, true);    
echo $inf['myInfluencers'][0]['entity']['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$inf = json_decode($myString, true);
echo $inf['myInfluencers'][0]['entity']['id'];

that is the syntax . thanks guys